# Ryzen 5 3600X stuck at 3800mhz

Tags: amd-processor, amd-ryzen

In `lscpu` it shows that CPU max MHz is 3800.0000 (3.8 ghz) why isn't it 4400 (4 ghz)?

Answer (score 1):

A CPU's clock speed rate is a measure of how many clock cycles a CPU can perform per second. The base clock of the AMD Ryzen 5 3600X CPU is 3.8GHz. The maximum boost clock of the Ryzen 5 3600X is up to 4.4GHz, but this CPU does not run at its maximum boost clock speed under conditions of normal use.

AMD Ryzen 5 3600X specs:

- Base clock: 3.8GHz
- Max boost clock: Up to 4.4GHz
- Total L2 cache: 3MB
- Total L3 cache: 32MB
- CMOS: TSMC 7nm FinFET